# NSCombobox too large

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscombobox

I was trying to create a mac application. But after I inserted the combobox using Interface Builder and run the application, I got the following message:

> This application is trying to draw a very large combo box, 28 points tall.  Vertically resizable combo boxes are not supported, but it happens that 10.4 and previous drew something that looked kind of sort of okay.  The art in 10.5 does not break up in a way that supports that drawing.  This application should be revised to stop using large combo boxes.  This warning will appear once per app launch.

I tried to change the height of the combobox to a smaller value. But unfortunately the height is fixed in the Interface builder. Anyone know an idea how to get rid of the warning?

Environment:

- Xcode 6
- Mac OS Yosemite
- Language: Objective C

Comment: try changing height, try 26 the default one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interface Builder (IB), Utilities, Size Inspector:  Change the Control Size from **Regular** to **Small** and then back to **Regular**.

It worked for me - got rid of the message shown in OP.

Comment: Thanks for saving me a ton of time.